# Perform action before given interval in setInterval has passed

Tags: javascript, setinterval

is there an option to check whether user performed an action during the interval? For example, I have elements which highlight randomly one by one with the interval 1000ms. And I should click on the active element during the interval. How to check whether I was successful ?

Comment: Don't use `setInterval`, use `setTimeout` and conditionally re-register the callback when you meet the condition

Comment: Like  `function test() { if (x == 10) { setTimeout(test, 1000); } } `

Comment: Thanks! But I have a task and it mustn't be changed, so I have a score container and if user doesn't click the element during interval, it must subtract 5 points. How can I implement that? I've already searched half of the internet and no results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something which might be what you are thinking of:

```js
const start = document.querySelector('#start');

const clickme = document.querySelector('#clickme');

start.addEventListener('click', function(){
  clickme.disabled = false;
  setTimeout(function(){
    clickme.disabled = true;
  }, 1000);
});

clickme.addEventListener('click', function(){
  alert('Yo!');
});
```

```html
<button id='start'>Start</button>
<button id='clickme' disabled>Click Me</button>
```